# How to compile and run a kotlin file which has dependencies on a jar from CLI?

Tags: kotlin, command-line-interface, kotlinc

I have a file called A.kt which has dependencies on B.jar. How to compile and run the kotlin file on CLI?

I have tried:

```
kotlinc A.kt -cp B.jar
```

but this did not work.

The error I get is:

```kotlin
A.kt:11:24: error: unresolved reference: B
        val b = B(
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `kotlinc -help` shows:

```
Usage: kotlinc-jvm <options> <source files>
```

That puts the options before the source files.  Which is pretty standard: most commands process their arguments in order, so I'd expect the command in the question to compile `A.kt` *before* setting up the classpath to include `B.jar`.

So you should try:

```
kotlinc -cp B.jar A.kt
```

Other potential causes include `B.jar` not being present in the current directory (or not being given along with the necessary path info), and it not containing the relevant `.class` files (in directories corresponding to their packages).

Comment: Same error with ```kotlinc -cp B.jar A.kt```

Comment: The .jar file works successfully in IntelliJ but I need it to get it working in CLI. The .jar is in the same folder as well and the path I give it correct as well. This is because when I try -verbose in the above command, I do not get any error. On the other hand if I enter the wrong path then I get the following error with verbose:


```warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: x/B.jar```